# Error when compiling Java program in terminal with javac

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When trying to compile program demonstrating the use of Binary Search Tree inside terminal, javac throws error on some line in my code.

[image]

Although when compiling exactly the same code within (https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler) no error encountered and works just fine.

Here's the actual code that i have to deal with.
https://codeshare.io/5Z03ve

Expected Output is:

Node with the key 75

Sales Manager has the key 75

Comment: If I cut your code from https://codeshare.io/5Z03ve and I run it on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler I get the same error

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your quesiton.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. It has already been marked as a duplicate of another question, no need to replace your question text with another link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention while copying code, you've changed class name so Java didn't know what BinaryTree is.

Replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
BinaryTree theTree = new BinaryTree();
```

By this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
JavaExercises theTree = new JavaExercises();
```